# Компиляция проекта на C++ из заголовочного файла

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Как компилировать проект на C++, находясь в *.h файле?
Это жутко неудобно, сделав изменения в заголовочном файле, переключаться на какой-либо cpp файл, чтоб нажать F7 для компиляции проекта. Ибо находясь в заголовочном файле меню "Компилировать" не доступно

[image]

Comment: Вроде было на любом доступно...

Comment: @Qwertiy, у меня в Visual Studio 2017 не доступно. Видно где-то в настройках галку надо поставить, но поиски не дали результатов

Comment: У меня VS2017 и компиляция из заголовочного файла работает нормально без каких-либо доп настроек. Причем даже когда заголовочный файл не принадлежит это проекту, а лежит в другом место и только инклюдится.

Comment: @VTT, проверил у сотрудника - такая же ситуация - в заголовочном файле меню "Сборка/Компилировать - F7" не доступно

Comment: Возможно у вас переопределены клавиши, и на F7 стоит компиляция текущего модуля, а не сборка решения (как по умолчанию).

Comment: Посмотрите, а лучше и нам покажите (добавив в вопрос картинку) как выглядит меню сборки, там должны быть горячие кнопки прописаны справа. Пример для [VS 2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRXSv.png).

Comment: Вы пишете "Компиляция проекта", но пытаетесь скомпилировать отдельный файл. Может быть, вам нужно "собрать решение"? `Ctrl+Shift+B`.

Comment: @maestro, верно. Я пытаюсь скомпилировать файл, а мне нужно компилировать (собрать) проект. Благодарю - разобрался